# Catching ANTLR's NoViableAltException in Java and ANTLRWorks Debugger

Tags: java, antlr

Consider we try to feed some incorrect input text to some grammar (e.g. text which contains some unknown token). In `ANTLRWorks` during interpretation we will see `NoViableAltException` in graph.

**UPD:** There are two cases when this exception appears:

1) Unexpected using of some known token, in this case we will receive something like `line 5:36 no viable alternative at input ','`

2) Using unknown token type. For example grammar doesn't know anything about tokens, which start with `@` symbol. And we are trying to feed text with such token to our grammar.

Unfortunately **in case (2) this exception isn't thrown** neither in `ANTLRWorks` debugger, neither in generated Java code; but it is seen only in `ANTLRWorks` interpreter's result graph.

I've tried also to add the following standard code to my grammar:

```
@parser::members {
    private IErrorReporter errorReporter = null;
    public void setErrorReporter(IErrorReporter errorReporter) {
        this.errorReporter = errorReporter;
    }
    public void emitErrorMessage(String msg) {
        errorReporter.reportError(msg);
    }
}
@lexer::members {
    ... the same code as above ...
}
```

This construction successfully catches parsing errors of type (1) (e.g. errors about unexpected using of token: `line 5:36 no viable alternative at input ','`). But in case of not-viable-input with unknown tokens parser generates just `children == null` in top `CommonTree` object without any error reporting.

I'm using `antlr 3.5`.

The question: is it possible to catch `NoViableAltException` in described situation in generated Java code and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15386679/1479414) given by [280Z28](https://stackoverflow.com/users/138304/280z28) to my [second part of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15385650/outofmemoryerror-when-parsing-incorrect-input-in-antlr) solves both problems well. So, this is the proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following as the *very last* rule in your lexer. It will create a token for the invalid character(s) and send it to the parser where the error will be properly reported.

```
ANYCHAR : . ;
```

Comment: Nice idea. **But it also doesn't give me any result**. There isn't any error for incorrect text.

Comment: Are you sure the input is getting tokenized properly (is the invalid `@` character from your input making it all the way to the parser)? You haven't posted a grammar so it's hard to test your situation.

Comment: I can confirm, that adding such `ANYCHAR` lexer rule can not solve the problem. But your answer on my second question about `OutofmemoryError` solves this problem well. It was clear, that both problems are interleaved.

Comment: Well, I think that difference between these two problems is in how deeply parser have to "dig" while parsing text with invalid token. If it not very deep, so it will be `null` result. If too deep, it will be `OutofmemoryError`.