# OutOfMemoryError when parsing incorrect input in ANTLR

Tags: java, antlr, out-of-memory

Actually this issue is related with my previous question [Catching ANTLR's NoViableAltException in Java and ANTLRWorks Debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15384800/catching-antlrs-noviablealtexception-in-java-and-antlrworks-debugger), but I decided to split them because of different symptoms.

The issue is about feeding to ANTLR input text, which contains unknown tokens. Consider for example, that our grammar doesn't known anything about tokens which start with `@` symbol. If we will try to feed such text to `ANTLRWorks` interpreter, we will receive `NoViableAltException` in result graph.

But if we will take generated and compiled grammar in Java and try to parse such invalid text with it, we can receive one of the following result (it depends on where we will place this unknown token, i.e. how "deeply" we will put it into text):

1) no errors, and `null` value in `chidlren` field in top-level `CommonTree` object (the mentioned question about is exactly about this case);

2) `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` error.

This question is about second case. How we could prevent this behaviour of `ANTLR` parser? For example, in production clients could accidentally crash down a system by providing incorrect char sequence to DSL parser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This generally happens when a lexer contains a rule that can match the empty string. For example, consider the following rule:

```
WS : (' ' | '\t')*;
```

This rule can create a `WS` token containing a total of 0 space and/or tab characters, which means there can be an infinite number of them between any other tokens in your input. During some situations involving invalid input, the error recovery process can be forced into an infinite loop which will buffer tokens until Java runs out of memory.

The first step to solving this situation is examining every lexer rule to make sure this can't happen. The `WS` should instead be written like this to ensure that *at least 1* space and/or tab characters are consumed.

```
WS : (' ' | '\t')+;
```

PS: ANTLR 4 performs a static check on the grammar to produce an error (4.0) or warning (4.0.1+) if this occurs.

Comment: Wow. Thank you a lot. You just solved not only this problem, but also this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15384800/catching-antlrs-noviablealtexception-in-java-and-antlrworks-debugger :)