Parsing with my example ANTLR grammar. Out of Memory Errors, despite 8GB heap
I have been working this grammar for several days now, with various improvements, but I am now parsing many files, some with syntax errors and stack overflow errors (which I or AI has fixed).   Now I'm getting Out of Memory Errors, and I could ask an AI, but perhaps it's time for humans?
Here's my grammar:
https://github.com/coderextreme/X3DJSONLD/blob/master/src/main/cplusplus/net/coderextreme/CPPONGrammar.g4
Here's my code:
https://github.com/coderextreme/X3DJSONLD/blob/master/src/main/cplusplus/net/coderextreme/CPP.java
Here's the command-line:
java -Xss1g -Xmx8g -cp "C:/Users/john/Downloads/antlr-4.13.1-complete.jar;." CPP data/gears.h

Here's what I'm trying to parse:
https://github.com/coderextreme/X3DJSONLD/blob/master/src/main/cplusplus/net/coderextreme/data/gears.h
I have not yet asked AI about OutOfMemoryErrors.  This isn't the only file with those errors.

Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15385650/outofmemoryerror-when-parsing-incorrect-input-in-antlr

Never catchException, always catch someting very specific you are expecting. (Remove the catch and see what you get.)

please post a [mre] in the question, not only as external links - external links can be changed, blocked, deleted, ... invalidating the question for other readers

@pts, the Java code was copied from someone else's example.  I believe the purpose is to retry parsing.

@pts I removed the try catch, and found out that the lines above the try threw an IOException, so I declared the main as throwing IOException.  I don't think I want to catch an out of memory error?

In general, don't catch anything, except when you already know and want to catch something very specific. Don't catch IOException. Don't catch out-of-memory errors.

@pts I know not to catch Exceptions, but in this case, it’s a way to try a different approach to parsing.  IDK if the operation returns an error or not, and there aren’t any Exceptions thrown from the method…so, I guess I’ll look for a return value in the documentation, unless you want to look it up for me.

I believe that left recursion solved my problem. The AI kept suggesting it.  Here's the code I changed in the grammar:
boolean_list : BOOLEAN (',' boolean_list)*;
integer_list : (SENTINEL | '-' WHOLE | '+'? WHOLE) (',' integer_list)*;
float_list : FLOAT (',' float_list)*;
string_list : cstring (',' string_list)*;

Changed to this:
boolean : 'true' | 'false';
boolean_list : boolean (',' boolean)*;
integer_list : (SENTINEL | '-' WHOLE | '+'? WHOLE) (',' (SENTINEL | '-' WHOLE | '+'? WHOLE))*;
float_list : FLOAT (',' FLOAT)*;
string_list : cstring (',' cstring)*;


There were a few other changes.

I guess I don't understand the difference between left recursion and right recursion.  Hmm

Those rules are each ambiguous. You don't need recursion at all because you are using kleene star operators. This has nothing to do with left vs right recursion.

Recursion is the AI's description what needed to be done.

Left recursion is where the target non-terminal symbol appears in the production on the left. Right recursion is where it appears on the right, as in your integer_list production in the "before" example. Right recursion is to be avoided in LR parsers, as it chews up stack.

To me, my problem was using recursion, and the AI (latter) solution was to use iteration.

Kleene operators replace recursion. So, write float_list as either float_list : FLOAT | ',' float_list; (right recursive) or float_list : float_list ',' FLOAT | FLOAT; (left recursive) or float_list: FLOAT (',' FLOAT)*; (Kleene closure). However, what you did, float_list : FLOAT (',' float_list)*;, is both, which you shouldn't do. Using both recursion and kleene operators causes ambiguity. (You should draw out the two possible CSTs for input 1,2,3.) While Antlr4 accepts ambiguity, the parser keeps track of all possible derivations. That causes pressure on the memory allocator.

If someone knows how to specify an integer list and a whole number plus sentinel list, that would be helpful.  Should be easy enough, I just don’t know if the parser will handle it, and as far as I know, the underlying library only has int and int32_t arrays
