# how to check if your query is empty using java

Tags: java, sql, spring

I'm using a spring framework and the code I'm using won't work or check if the query is null, though I used a .isEmpty() method it doesn't mean that the query is empty. I wanted to make sure that my query is empty because a part of my code does invoke an id in which case I didn't even though its null so please help me T.T

```
public List<Object> searchEmployee(EmployeeSearchDto data) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    final String CRITERIA_EMPLOYEEID = "emp.employeeID =:id";
    final String CRITERIA_EMPLOYEEID2 = "emp.employeeID LIKE:id";
    final String CRITERIA_POSITION= "emp.positionID =:posID";
    final String CRITERIA_DEPARTMENT="emp.departmentID =:deptID";
    final String CRITERIA_WORKPLACE = "emp.workplaceID =:workID";

    Boolean selected_dept = false;
    Boolean selected_pos = false;
    Boolean selected_work = false;
    Boolean input_empID = false;
    Boolean input_empName = false;
    firstName = "";
    middleName = "";
    lastName = "";
    completeName = "";
    firstLastName = ""; 

    List<String> criteria = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Object> employees = null;

    // checking the fields if all the fields is empty
    try{
        //one by one check the select field
        String query = "Select"
                + " emp.employeeID,"
                +"emp.firstName,"
                +"emp.middleName,"
                +"emp.lastName,"
                +"pos.positionName,"
                +"dept.deptName,"
                +"work.workplaceName"
                +"from Employee emp "
                + "INNER JOIN Department dept "
                    + "ON emp.departmentID = dept.deptID " 
                + "INNER JOIN Position pos " 
                    + "ON emp.positionID = pos.positionID "
                + "INNER JOIN Workplace work " 
                    + "ON emp.workplaceID = work.workplaceID ";

                if(!data.isEmpty()) {

                    query = query.concat("WHERE ");
                    if(data.getEmployeeID()!="" && data.getEmployeeID()!=null) {    
                        criteria.add(CRITERIA_EMPLOYEEID2);
                        System.out.println("Employee IDs");
                        input_empID = true;
                    } 

                    if(data.getEmployeeName()!="" && data.getEmployeeName()!=null){ 
                        criteria.add(nameCriteriaHelper(data.getEmployeeName()));
                        System.out.println("Employee Name AKOOO");
                        input_empName = true;
                    }

                    if(data.getDepartmentID()!=0) {
                        criteria.add(CRITERIA_DEPARTMENT);
                        System.out.println("Dept ID ");
                        selected_dept = true;
                    }
                    if(data.getPositionID()!=0) {
                        criteria.add(CRITERIA_POSITION);
                        System.out.println("POS ID ");
                        selected_pos = true;
                    }
                    if(data.getWorkplaceID()!=0) {
                        criteria.add(CRITERIA_WORKPLACE);
                        selected_work = true;
                    }

                    query = query.concat(String.join(" OR ", criteria));
                }
                query = query.concat(" ORDER BY emp.joinDate DESC");
                System.out.println("QUERY: " + query);
                Query q = session.createQuery(query);
                if(input_empID) {
                    q.setParameter("id", "%" + data.getEmployeeID() + "%");
                }
                if(input_empName) {
                    if(searchbyOne)
                        q.setParameter("inputName", "%" + data.getEmployeeName() + "%");
                    if(searchbyFandL)
                        q.setParameter("firstLastName", "%" +firstLastName+ "%");
                    if(searchbyCompName)
                        q.setParameter("completeName", "%" +completeName+ "%");
                }

                if(selected_dept) {
                    q.setParameter("deptID", data.getDepartmentID());
                }
                if(selected_pos) {
                    q.setParameter("posID", data.getPositionID());
                }
                if(selected_work) {
                    q.setParameter("workID", data.getWorkplaceID());
                }
                employees = (List<Object>) q.list();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        session.close();
    }

    return employees;
}
public String nameCriteriaHelper(String name) {
    searchbyOne = false;
    searchbyFandL = false;
    searchbyCompName = false;

    final String noOfTokens_1 = "CONCAT(emp.lastName,'  ',emp.firstName, ' ',emp.middleName) LIKE :inputName";
    final String noOfTokens_2 = "(CONCAT(emp.lastName, ' ', emp.firstName) LIKE :firstLastName "
            + "OR CONCAT(emp.firstName, ' ', emp.lastName) LIKE :firstLastName)";
    final String noOfTokens_3 = "CONCAT(emp.lastName,' ',emp.firstName, ' ',emp.middleName) LIKE :completeName";

    StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(name);
    int no_of_tokens = stringTokenizer.countTokens();

    switch(no_of_tokens) {
    case 1: searchbyOne = true;
            return noOfTokens_1;
    case 2: firstName = stringTokenizer.nextToken();
            lastName = stringTokenizer.nextToken();
            firstLastName = lastName + " " + firstName;
            searchbyFandL = true;
            return noOfTokens_2;

    default: int counter = 0;
            while( counter < (no_of_tokens - 2)) {
            firstName = firstName.concat(stringTokenizer.nextToken() + " ");
            counter++;
            }

            firstName = stringTokenizer.nextToken();
            middleName = stringTokenizer.nextToken();
            lastName = stringTokenizer.nextToken();
            completeName = lastName + " " + firstName + " " + middleName;
            searchbyCompName = true;
            return noOfTokens_3;

    }
```

Comment: post your code here.

Comment: check the question above again :) i edit some code in it

Comment: which part of the code you want to check for null? This check `if(data.getEmployeeID()!="" && data.getEmployeeID()!=null)`?

Comment: the emp.employeeID in the query if i can

Comment: yes that also checks but the employeeID is not really null and invokes a query volutarily (i print the query to check)

Comment: Ah, what you want is to check for `emp.employeeId` which is check null in database, right?

Comment: yes because it shows in the query that I print that i invoke it even though its text field is empty at all

Comment: if the employeeID is null and has been check before the query starts, maybe the following code will go as i expected it to be

Comment: Check the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using wrong order and wrong function to compare string:

Replace:

```
data.getEmployeeID()!="" && data.getEmployeeID()!=null
```

With

```
data.getEmployeeID() != null && !data.getEmployeeID().equals("")
```

Comparing string must use `equals()`. And check for `null` should be done first, before accessing the `equals` method

You should correct other conditions as above too.

Comment: im checking if it works, btw, what's the difference between (!="" vs .equals("") )???

Comment: You should read about equals in java. It's a big topic. But to simplify, the == or != compare object rẻence, ưhile equals take into account other condition also

Comment: its still showing itself T.T <br/> Calling database...
Employee IDs
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
        at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1967)
        at com.rgtc.ads.v2.dao.impl.employeedetails.SearchEmployeeDaoImpl.nameCriteriaHelper(SearchEmployeeDaoImpl.java:163)

Comment: Check my edited answer. THe correct expression is `data.getEmployeeID() != null && !data.getEmployeeID().equals("")
`

Comment: thanks, problem solved. But another problem arises hahahaha and that's for me to find out :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the logic that Mr. Nguyễn provided here is faulty. An object or variable cannot both be `null` and initialized to a default value (such as `foo == ""`) at the same time.

At the time of the logic check, if the String is in fact null, the second half of the logic statement will engage, checking to see if the String is equal to `""`, which will throw a `null pointer exception`. Instead of checking for both at the same time, check for one and then check for the other like so:

```
//since two logic checks are being performed, 
//it is advantageous to put the data from the query
//into memory so you don't have to get the 
//same result twice
String foo = data.getEmployeeID();

if (foo != null)
{
    if (!(foo.equals("")))
    {
        //the result is neither null or empty
    }
    else
    {
        //the result is not null but it is empty
    }
}
else
{
    //the result is null
}
```

Comment: actually i'm getting an exception: antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token:  ... Btw, if that's the case, should i put this with in the try catch before the query starts or the other way around?

Comment: @user9768584 Well, the logic I wrote above was to help avoid a null pointer exception, and will definitely help you isolate null or empty queries. I believe that this is a different question entirely and you should go ahead and ask a new one since this is getting off topic...

Comment: @user9768584 However, if it's any consolation I looked into that error a little bit and found that this may be due to attempting to parse incorrect input, yet the error may even be in a different part of your program as evidenced by this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15384800/catching-antlrs-noviablealtexception-in-java-and-antlrworks-debugger) For now, I would attempt to see if my above logic fixes the problem, then go forward from there - best of luck.

Comment: @user9768584 When in doubt, try it before you "buy" it. Also, it may be wise to start splitting up portions of the program in the try/catch into smaller modules/functions - doing this greatly helps with the debugging of the code: that try statement is _massive_.